# office 365 word integration in codeigniter 4

Tags: codeigniter

Having issue in integration of office 365 for which i ahve registered to this portal https://portal.azure.com/
// This is basic permissions i have given still having issue to edit word document

```
$loginUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenant_id/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?" .
            "client_id=$clientId" .
            "&redirect_uri=$redirectUri" .
            "&response_type=code" .
            "&scope=openid profile offline_access User.Read Files.ReadWrite.All Sites.Read.All";
```

[This issue i am getting on edit word doucument , document file not able to open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtDTD.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.